# Oracle SELECT TOP 10 records

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I have an big problem with an SQL Statement in Oracle. I want to select the TOP 10 Records ordered by STORAGE_DB which aren't in a list from an other select statement.

This one works fine for all records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  APP_ID, 
  NAME, 
  STORAGE_GB, 
  HISTORY_CREATED, 
  TO_CHAR(HISTORY_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS HISTORY_DATE  
  FROM HISTORY WHERE 
      STORAGE_GB IS NOT NULL AND 
        APP_ID NOT IN (SELECT APP_ID
                       FROM HISTORY
                        WHERE TO_CHAR(HISTORY_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') = '06.02.2009')
```

But when I am adding

```
AND ROWNUM <= 10
ORDER BY STORAGE_GB DESC
```

I'm getting some kind of "random" Records. I think because the limit takes in place before the order.

Does someone has an good solution? The other problem: This query is realy slow (10k+ records)

Answer (score 250, accepted):

You'll need to put your current query in subquery as below :

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
  APP_ID, 
  NAME, 
  STORAGE_GB, 
  HISTORY_CREATED, 
  TO_CHAR(HISTORY_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS HISTORY_DATE  
  FROM HISTORY WHERE 
    STORAGE_GB IS NOT NULL AND 
      APP_ID NOT IN (SELECT APP_ID FROM HISTORY WHERE TO_CHAR(HISTORY_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') ='06.02.2009')
  ORDER BY STORAGE_GB DESC )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

Oracle applies [rownum](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/rownum.html) to the result after it has been returned.
 You need to filter the result after it has been returned, so a subquery is required. You can also use [RANK()](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/rank.html) function to get Top-N results.

For performance try using `NOT EXISTS` in place of `NOT IN`. See [this](http://www.4tm.com.ar/4tmsite/wordpress/?p=25) for more.

Comment: NOT EXISTS is not working in this scenario (invalid relational operator) APP_ID NOT EXISTS (SELEC...)

Comment: Some may say that this is apt to turn people off to Oracle.

Comment: Check the `FETCH NEXT N ROWS ONLY` answer below.

Comment: @Padmarag : When is a rownum apply in a query like this one - Select * from SomeTable where someColumn = '123' and rownum <=3. Is it after selecting the results from  [Select * from SomeTable where someColumn = '123' ]

Comment: try to use:  select * from (select * from history order by storage_gb desc) where rownum < 10; --(modify inner query to fetch distinct records)

Answer (score 134):

If you are using Oracle 12c, use:

> FETCH NEXT ***N*** ROWS ONLY

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  APP_ID, 
  NAME, 
  STORAGE_GB, 
  HISTORY_CREATED, 
  TO_CHAR(HISTORY_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS HISTORY_DATE  
  FROM HISTORY WHERE 
    STORAGE_GB IS NOT NULL AND 
      APP_ID NOT IN (SELECT APP_ID FROM HISTORY WHERE TO_CHAR(HISTORY_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') ='06.02.2009')
  ORDER BY STORAGE_GB DESC
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html

Comment: this is gold compared to other answer

Comment: If someone could say why it's better, that would be a good comment/edit.

Comment: If using simple query like `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ROWNUM<=10` and `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`, `FETCH NEXT` seems like more costly since it will do this predicate `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY  NULL )<=10)` if check from the Explain Plan.

Answer (score 58):

try

```
SELECT * FROM users FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 23):

With regards to the poor performance there are any number of things it could be, and it really ought to be a separate question.  However, there is one obvious thing that could be a problem:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(HISTORY_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') = '06.02.2009')
```

If HISTORY_DATE really is a date column and if it has an index then this rewrite will perform better:

```
WHERE HISTORY_DATE = TO_DATE ('06.02.2009', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

This is because a datatype conversion disables the use of a B-Tree index.

Answer (score 16):

You get an apparently random set because ROWNUM is applied before the ORDER BY. So your query takes the first ten rows and sorts them.0 To select the top ten salaries you should use an analytic function in a subquery, then filter that:

```
 select * from 
     (select empno,
             ename,
             sal,
             row_number() over(order by sal desc nulls last) rnm
    from emp) 
 where rnm<=10
```

Answer (score -2):

you may use this query for selecting top records in oracle. Rakesh B

select * from User_info where id >= (select max(id)-10 from User_info);

Comment: Hey Rakesh! I'm not sure this answer fully addresses the question posed. Check out some of the other responses that provide more detail and are well-formatted for some examples.