# Alternate of sql server TOP in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How to get top 3 records in oracle pl sql?i am new to oracle,earlier i have used sql server.

My requirement is to get distinct top 3 records of Column X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SELECT TOP 10 records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498035/oracle-select-top-10-records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to retrieve the Top N records from a query, you can use the following syntax::-

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (your ordered query) alias_name
 WHERE rownum <= Rows_to_return
```

Example:-

```
SELECT *
 FROM (select * from suppliers ORDER BY supplier_name) suppliers2
 WHERE rownum <= 3
```

Comment: There is no need for `order by rownum`, it is a psuedocolumn generated in the order that rows are returned, i.e. by definition it's orderd.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
SELECT ename, sal 
  FROM ( SELECT ename, sal, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sal DESC) sal_rank
           FROM emp ) 
 WHERE sal_rank <= 3;
```

Comment: This will incur an additional table or index scan for no reason.