# JAVA: sqlite throws exception after writing a few records?

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc, sql-insert

I am trying to write a few thousand records to sqlite DB. However after writing a random number of records - 122 / 45 / 180, it throws following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: unable to open database file
```

The random number of records get populated on DB but this error stops further record writing. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
Class loginModel:

private connection;

public loginModel(){
        connection = SqLiteConnection.connector();
        if(connection == null)
            System.exit(1);
    }

public boolean interactWithDB() throws SQLException{

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    String query;

    try {
        query = "";
        DBPopulator dbPopulator = new DBPopulator();
        dbPopulator.populateData();
        List<dbData> dataList = dbPopulator.getdbData();
        Iterator<dbData> it = dataList.listIterator(); 
        while(it.hasNext()){
            dbData data = it.next();
            query = getNewInsertQuery(data); // builds query based on data input
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();  
        }                   
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
    finally{
        if(preparedStatement!=null)
            preparedStatement.close();
        if(resultSet!=null)
            resultSet.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

And I am getting the new connection through:

Class: SqLiteConnection

```
public static Connection connector(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");           
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\akshaysu\\Documents\\r_sqlite.sqlite");
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        return conn;
    }       
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("DB not found");
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

EXCEPTION:

```
java.sql.SQLException: unable to open database file
    at org.sqlite.DB.execute(DB.java:275)
    at org.sqlite.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:281)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.executeUpdate(PrepStmt.java:77)
    at application.loginModel.interactWithDB(loginModel.java:98)
    at application.loginController.buttonAction(loginController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT3:

```
private String getNewInsertQuery(dbData e){
        String query = "";
        query = "insert into r_sqlite (NAME, AGE, COMPANY-NAME) VALUES(";
        query += e.getName()+", ";
        query += e.getAge()+", ";
        query += e.getCompany();
        query += ");";      
        return query;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: sounds like reopening the connection per insert... Resource leak?!

Comment: let me update the question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following things fixed the problem. Thanks Jan for suggesting the changes:

1. Batching
2. Doing manual commit instead of auto commit.

Here's the code snippet:

```
connection.setAutocommit(false);
try(PreparedStatement ps = 
            connection.prepareStatement("insert into r_sqlite (NAME, AGE, COMPANY-NAME) VALUES(?,?,?)")) {
      Iterator<dbData> it = dataList.listIterator();
      int batchCount = 0;
      while(it.hasNext()) {
        dbData data = it.next();
        ps.setString(1,  data.getName());
        ps.setInt(2,  data.getAge());
        ps.setString(3,  data.getCompany());
        ps.addBatch();
        if(++batchCount % 1000 == 0) {
            ps.executeBatch();
            ps.clearBatch(); 
        }
      }
      ps.executeBatch();
      connection.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Some notes on your code you might want to set right:

- You keep creating new statements in your while:

  ```
  while(it.hasNext()){
      dbData data = it.next();
      query = getNewInsertQuery(data); 
      //This is never closed!
      preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();  
  }
  ```

try to do it try-with-resource style:

```
   while(it.hasNext()){
        dbData data = it.next();
        query = getNewInsertQuery(data); 
        //This whill always be closed!
        try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
           preparedStatement.executeUpdate();  
        }
    }
```

- You create the connection in login() but close in finally: Try keeping it together

  ```
  public boolean interactWithDB() throws SQLException{  
    try (Connection connection = SqLiteConnection.connector()) {
      String query = "";
      DBPopulator dbPopulator = new DBPopulator();
      dbPopulator.populateData();
      List<dbData> dataList = dbPopulator.getdbData();
      Iterator<dbData> it = dataList.listIterator(); 
      while(it.hasNext()){
          dbData data = it.next();
          query = getNewInsertQuery(data); // builds query based on data input
          try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
              preparedStatement.executeUpdate();  
          }
      }                   
      return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
   }    
  }
  ```

Now try again and share full Exception Stacktrace if it still doesn't work.

**EDIT 2**

- Any other iteractions with the database? Do you use it someplace else?
- Can you share getNewInsertQuery(data) - is that SAME query (different values) or DIFFERENT queries?

**EDIT 3 - Use Batching**

```
    try(PreparedStatement ps = 
            connection.prepareStatement("insert into r_sqlite (NAME, AGE, COMPANY-NAME) VALUES(?,?,?)")) {
      Iterator<dbData> it = dataList.listIterator();
      int batchCount = 0;
      while(it.hasNext()) {
        dbData data = it.next();
        ps.setString(1,  data.getName());
        ps.setInt(2,  data.getAge());
        ps.setString(3,  data.getCompany());
        ps.addBatch();
        if(++batchCount % 1000 == 0) {
            ps.executeBatch();  
        }
      }
      ps.executeBatch();
    }
```

Comment: This time it ran for a bit longer and created 500 entries but it again failed. I have added the full stack trace under EDIT2 section on my question as I was not able to put it in this comment.

Comment: EDIT 2 not (yet?) visible

Comment: see my edit 2 - some more ideas. How do you figure it ran for 500 items this time?

Comment: I just saw the number of rows populated in db

Comment: I added the function getNewInsertQuery(data). 
No other interactions with this db.

Comment: Again, it's running for small iterations like 70, 83 etc.

Comment: see my edit 4 for proper use of preparedStatement and SQL batching - you don't do this on multiple threads, do you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99699/discussion-between-akshay-and-jan).

Comment: Thanks Jan.
In your solution, I had to do a couple of changes and now it works.
1. Had to use clearBatch() otherwise column auto_id not unique error was popping up. 
2. I set auto-commit = false and did manual commit instead.