# How to Select Top 100 rows in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement is to get each client's latest order, and then get top 100 records.

I wrote one query as below to get latest orders for each client. Internal query works fine. But I don't know how to get first 100 based on the results.

```
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT id, client_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY create_time DESC) rn 
      FROM order
    ) WHERE rn=1
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want the first 100 for each client, or the first 100 clients?

Comment: I want first 100 clients' latest order.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Assuming that create_time contains the time the order was created, and you want the 100 clients with the latest orders, you can:

- add the create_time in your innermost query
- order the results of your outer query by the `create_time desc`
- add an outermost query that filters the first 100 rows using `ROWNUM`

Query:

```
  SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
          id, 
          client_id, 
          create_time,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY create_time DESC) rn 
        FROM order
      ) 
      WHERE rn=1
      ORDER BY create_time desc
  ) WHERE rownum <= 100
```

**UPDATE for Oracle 12c**

With release 12.1, Oracle introduced ["real" Top-N queries](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries). Using the new `FETCH FIRST...` syntax, you can also use:

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      client_id, 
      create_time,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY create_time DESC) rn 
    FROM order
  ) 
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY create_time desc
  FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY)
```

Comment: Actually I am confused, if I don't put another SELECT on top of my first query, but write ROWNUM<101 next to rn=1. Why the two results are different?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
          id, 
          client_id, 
          create_time,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY create_time DESC) rn 
        FROM order
      ) 
      WHERE rn=1 AND rownum<=100
      ORDER BY create_time desc`

Comment: Because in that case, you aren't sorting your rows by the create_time - your result set is randomly ordered, and you just take the first 100; that's essentially a random sample.

Comment: It just gets top random 100 orders whose rn=1, right?

Comment: Yes. _this_comment_was_too_short_

Comment: @user2321728 No. The query that confuses you gets 100 random orders (since row numbers are effectively random) and *then* filters those 100 where `rn = 1`.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you running? `select * from v$version`

Comment: Guys ... the 12.1 version is terrible and the prior one is outrageous! Do the people at Oracle not see how easy this is in SQL Server, MySQL, and PostGreSQL?

Comment: @micahhoover never have I thought that doing TOP x is not easy in different environment.

Answer (score 75):

you should use rownum in oracle to do what you seek

```
where rownum <= 100
```

see also those answers to help you

[limit in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

[select top in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451534/how-to-do-top-1-in-oracle)

[select top in oracle 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498035/oracle-select-top-10-records)

Comment: There are two ways to do this.`SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT id, client_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY create_time DESC) rn 
      FROM order
    ) WHERE rn=1) WHERE ROWNUM < 101`Or `SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT id, client_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY create_time DESC) rn 
      FROM order
    ) WHERE rn=1 AND ROWNUM<101` I test these two, the results are different.

Answer (score 15):

As Moneer Kamal said, you can do that simply:

```
SELECT id, client_id FROM order 
WHERE rownum <= 100
ORDER BY create_time DESC;
```

Notice that the ordering is done **after** getting the 100 row. This might be useful for who does not want ordering.

Update:

To use **order by** with **rownum** you have to write something like this:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT id, client_id FROM order ORDER BY create_time DESC) WHERE rownum <= 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

To select top n rows updated recently

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT * 
   FROM table 
   ORDER BY UpdateDateTime DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM < 101;
```

Answer (score 0):

First 10 customers inserted into db (table customers):

```
select * from customers where customer_id <=
(select  min(customer_id)+10 from customers)

Last 10 customers inserted into db (table customers):

select * from customers where customer_id >=
(select  max(customer_id)-10 from customers)
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: Your queries assume that there are no gaps in customer_id. If that assumption is wrong (because rows were deleted, because the sequence used to populate the PK uses caching / an increment greater than 1 / ...), it will return fewer rows than requested.

Answer (score 0):

First, to just get the first N rows in a table regardless of any ordering this will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Order
WHERE ROWNUM <= N;
```

But say you want to get the last 50 orders?

```
SELECT *
FROM Order
WHERE ROWNUM <=N
ORDER BY Created_date DESC;
```

This would actually retrieve the first N rows then sort them by the Created_Date.

What is needed is to sort the records by date first then get the N rows

```
SELECT * 
FROM Order
ORDER BY Created_date DESC
FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY;
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM Order
  ORDER BY Created_Date DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <=N;
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
   SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      client_id, 
      create_time,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY create_time DESC) rn 
    FROM order
  ) 
  WHERE rn=1
  ORDER BY create_time desc) alias_name
WHERE rownum <= 100
ORDER BY rownum;
```

Or TOP:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Customers; //But not supported in Oracle
```

**NOTE:** I suppose that your internal query is fine. Please share your output of this.

Comment: It gave error like "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected." I don't think TOP works.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support TOP

Comment: Sorry but i dont have oracle installed yet in my system it is basic SQL command, thats why i ask for the output

Comment: Edited try this for oracle