# rank function with sum

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sum, rank

I have two tables.

```
abc(CID(pk), cname,)
order(order_id(pk), CID(fk), number_of_rentals)
```

I want to determine top 10 customers on the basis of number of movies they rented.

```
select 
    orders.cid,orders.no_rentals, abc.name, 
    rank() over (order by no_rentals desc) "rank" 
from abc 
inner join orders on orders.CID = abc.CID;
```

I used this query but it's not universal. How can I use sum function on number_of_rentals with this query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SELECT TOP 10 records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498035/oracle-select-top-10-records)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Top 10 
         orders.cid
       , abc.name
       , SUM(orders.no_rentals) TotalRentals
       , rank() over (order by SUM(orders.no_rentals) desc) [rank] 
from abc 
inner join orders on orders.CID = abc.CID
Group By orders.cid, abc.name
Order By TotalRentals DESC
```

Comment: SELECT  cid, sum(no_rentals) as sum 
FROM orders 
group by cid, no_rentals order by no_rentals desc ;    this query also gives result but how can i fetch top 10 rows using this query.. i am using oracle sql developer

Comment: your query gives error from keyword not found where expected