# How to SELECT top 10 products most sells?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table named "items" where are stored information about each product sold in each order, but I want to retrieve top 10 orders with max quantity of products sells. I've executed a SELECT statement to retrieve number of products sold in each orders but I don't know How I can retrieve only TOP 10 orders. Thanks.

```
SELECT   codigo_orden AS ORDER_ID, COUNT(codigo_producto) AS PRODUCTS_SOLD
FROM     cs_items
GROUP BY codigo_orden
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

[image]

But I just want to retrieve TOP 10 most products sold!! Something like that:

[image]

Comment: if there are ties in counts, do you only need one? and how should that be chosen?

Comment: see https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries

Comment: I only need top 10 Orders doesn't matter if there are two orders with same x number of products.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SELECT TOP 10 records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498035/oracle-select-top-10-records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 12c, you can use the row limiting clause, something like

```
SELECT   codigo_orden AS ORDER_ID, COUNT(codigo_producto) AS PRODUCTS_SOLD
FROM     cs_items
GROUP BY codigo_orden
ORDER BY 2 DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

If you are not using 12c, then you can use a window function, for example

```
select order_id, products_sold
from (
    SELECT   codigo_orden AS ORDER_ID, 
             COUNT(codigo_producto) AS PRODUCTS_SOLD,
             rank() over (order by count(codigo_producto) ) as rnk
    FROM     cs_items
    GROUP BY codigo_orden
)
where rnk <= 10
order by products_sold
```

You might need to use dense_rank() vs rank(), depending on how you want to handle ties.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: @Rattlesnake. I have expanded my answer based on your comment.

Comment: From the OP's answer to follow-up questions, and from the example he provided, it seems he will need `row_number()` rather than `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select ORDER_ID, PRODUCTS_SOLD
from (
SELECT   codigo_orden AS ORDER_ID, COUNT(codigo_producto) AS PRODUCTS_SOLD
FROM     cs_items
GROUP BY codigo_orden
ORDER BY 2 DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```