# Cannot query top 25 summed values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having difficulty querying the top 25 values. My table contains transaction dates, locations, UPC number, and sales quantity.

This is what I have so far -

SELECT
     date_id as "Date", store_id as "Store", sum(Sales_Unit) as "Total Sales"
FROM
    fact_pos_sales
    GROUP BY date_id, store_id
    ORDER BY "Total Sales" DESC
;

This is what I'm hoping to get as my result, except for just the top 25 values. I've tried adding "Top 25" next to Select, or adding a "Limit 25" at the end of my sql, except none of these two methods work. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer, for what it's worth.

[Current output, without the limit in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhN59.png)

Would someone be able to advise? I've been trying to search for the answers on Stockoverflow and elsewhere for the past two hours, with no results. Thank you!

Comment: `TOP` is for SQL Server, `LIMIT` for MySQL, in Oracle you can use `rownum`

Comment: existing answer from before, I think it's what you need
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2498058/2175524

Comment: Thank you Alberto and Goran!

Answer (score 0):

Not all database systems support the `SELECT TOP` clause (that's for `SQL Server`). `MySQL` supports the `LIMIT` clause to select a limited number of records, while `Oracle` uses `ROWNUM`.

Therefore something like:

```
SELECT * From 
 (
     SELECT date_id as "Date", store_id as "Store", sum(Sales_Unit) as "Total Sales" 
     FROM fact_pos_sales 
     GROUP BY date_id, store_id 
     ORDER BY "Total Sales" DESC
 ) 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From
(
   SELECT date_id as "Date", 
          store_id as "Store", 
          sum(Sales_Unit) as "Total Sales" 
     FROM fact_pos_sales 
    GROUP BY date_id, store_id 
    ORDER BY "Total Sales" DESC ;
) 
Where RowNum <=25
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c:

```
SELECT date_id as "Date", 
      store_id as "Store", 
      sum(Sales_Unit) as "Total Sales" 
FROM fact_pos_sales 
GROUP BY date_id, store_id 
ORDER BY "Total Sales" DESC
FETCH FIRST 25 ROWS ONLY;
```