# distinct SQL - return single rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the below records :

```
Column A   Column B

1           XX
2           XX
3           XX
4           XX
```

How can I display *1 record* by only using `ColumnB` but not using `ColumnA`. 
Like I should say

`select from Table T where ColumnB ='XX'`

and only *1 row* should return.

Comment: Please use line breaks to make your sample data more readable. currently it looks like it is only onw row, which I guess is not what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SELECT TOP 10 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498035/oracle-select-top-10-records)

Answer (score 1):

You may use one of the following :

```
with t(colA,ColB) as
(  
 select 1,'XX' from dual union all
 select 2,'XX' from dual union all
 select 3,'XX' from dual union all
 select 4,'XX' from dual    
)
select ColB 
  from t
 where ColumnB = 'XX' and rownum = 1;
```

or

```
select ColB from
(
    with t(colA,ColB) as
    (  
     select 1,'XX' from dual union all
     select 2,'XX' from dual union all
     select 3,'XX' from dual union all
     select 4,'XX' from dual    
    )
    select ColB,
           row_number() over (order by ColB) as rn
      from t
)
where ColumnB = 'XX' and rn=1;
```

or if your DB version is `12c`, this one works also :

```
with t(colA,ColB) as
(  
 select 1,'XX' from dual union all
 select 2,'XX' from dual union all
 select 3,'XX' from dual union all
 select 4,'XX' from dual    
)
select ColB 
from t
where ColumnB ='XX'
fetch {first|next} 1 {row|rows} only;
```

one of the keywords `first` or `next` and `row` or `rows` should be preferred.

Comment: None of these queries will return the correct result if you change the first row's `COLB` value to, say, `AAA`. Presumably, there are other values in the table, regarding condition the OP mentioned (`ColumnB ='XX'`) which you never used.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't care which one of the matching records is returned just use the `rownum` pseudo-column:

```
select * from Table T where ColumnB ='XX' 
and rownum = 1;
```

This query simply returns the first row from the result set. It is the cheapest way to get one row. The result is non-deterministic because there is no sort order, and there can't be: `rownum` doesn't play nice with ORDER BY which is why it's important that you don't care which row comes back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
select from Table T where ColumnB ='XX' group by ColunmB
```

Comment: Sorry Didn't see the oracle tag!

Answer (score 0):

As you don't really care which `a` to return, how about

```
SQL> with test (a, b) as
  2  (select 1, 'xx' from dual union all
  3   select 2, 'xx' from dual union all
  4   select 3, 'yy' from dual
  5  )
  6  select min(a) a, min(b) b
  7  from test
  8  where b = 'xx';

         A B
---------- --
         1 xx

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for the ideas.

I tried on of the below and it worked for me,

select a.column_name FROM  tale_name a
       WHERE ROWID IN (
                       select RID FROM
                        (
                          SELECT ROWID RID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.column_name ORDER BY ROWID) RN
                          FROM table_name a where column_name in 
                             (Select TO_CHAR(column_name) from diff_table_name)
                        ) WHERE RN = 1