# oracle - how to order by with date in the format dd-MMM-yy

Tags: oracle

I am able to select records and all like in the query below but select statement is picking records randomly that were create after the specified date. I am curious if there is a way to order by this date in the format dd-MMM-yy like 05-MAY-21..

```
              select * from Employees 
              where createDt >= '05-MAY-21'
              order by CreateDt asc
```

This statement is not giving what I am hoping for, which is start with records from date 05, 06, etc..

thank you in advance.

Comment: What data type is the CreateDt column? Is it actually a `date` or a `timestamp` type? What output are you getting from the query exactly that is a problem? It looks like it should work fine if CreateDt is a `date` type.

Comment: CreateDt has a datatype of DATE

Comment: and the order in which the records are weird.. like dates in the order of 08, 11, 12, 24, 24, 27, 27, 31, etc

Comment: What's weird? They're still in ascending order, as requested...

Answer (score 3):

> date in the format dd-MMM-yy like 05-MAY-21

A `DATE` is a binary data-type and it does **NOT** have any format.

If you do:

```sql
select *
from   Employees 
where  createDt >= DATE '2021-05-05'
order by CreateDt asc
```

Then it will sort the dates in ascending order by year then by month and then by day and then by hour and then by minute and then by second (yes, a `DATE` always has a time component).

If you do:

```sql
select *
from   Employees 
where  createDt >= '05-MAY-21'
order by CreateDt asc
```

Then you are implicitly asking Oracle to convert the string to a `DATE` and your query is actually doing:

```sql
select *
from   Employees 
where  createDt >= TO_DATE(
                     '05-MAY-21',
                     ( SELECT value
                       FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                       WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
                   )
order by CreateDt asc
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter does not match the format of your string then you will get unexpected results.

---

If you want to order the dates alphabetically, rather than chronologically then convert them to a string in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
select *
from   Employees 
where  createDt >= DATE '2021-05-05'
order by TO_CHAR(CreateDt, 'DD-MON-YY') asc
```

*However, I'm not sure hy you would want to do this.*

Comment: If I use 
select * from Employees 
where PROCESS = 'REGISTER' and Create_dt >= '09-MAY-17'
order by Request_id asc is giving me what I want.. But how do I limit that to send only 10 records? when I add Rownum <=10, its returning not in the same order like the query intially showed..

Comment: @challengeAccepted - What version of Oracle are you using?  If you want to use `rownum`, you'd need to nest the query with the `order by`.  If you're using a recent version of Oracle, you can use `fetch first 10 rows only`.

Comment: @challengeAccepted That is an entirely different question to the one that is asked and is covered by [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2498035/1509264). It is not working for you as the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column is generated before the `ORDER BY` is applied so you are getting 10 random rows and then ordering them by date; as JustinCave said, you need to order first and then wrap it in another sub-query and apply the `ROWNUM` filter there (as per the accepted answer in the question I linked to).

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` clause seems to be *wrong*.

You said that `createDt` column's datatype is `DATE`. So, why are you comparing it to a string? Use date literal or `TO_DATE` function, don't rely on implicit datatype conversion.

```
select * from Employees 
where createDt >= date '2021-05-05'  -- No! '05-MAY-21'
order by CreateDt asc
```

---

If, on the other hand, you only *think* that column's datatype is `DATE` but is - actually - `VARCHAR2`, then you'll have to "convert" it to a valid date value using `TO_DATE` function with appropriate date format mask, hoping that **all** values in that column have the same, valid format:

```
select * from Employees 
where to_date(createDt, 'dd-mmm-yy', 'nls_date_language = english') >= date '2021-05-05'
order by to_date(createDt, 'dd-mmm-yy', 'nls_date_language = english') asc
```

---

If none of above helps, please, post some sample data. That includes `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` several sample rows.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you showed what results you're getting and what are your desired results...

Anyway, I'm trying to guess basing on the question and your comments

Let's start with "... statement is picking records randomly ..."
and "This statement is not giving what I am hoping for, which is start with records from date 05, 06, etc.."
and later: "and the order in which the records are weird.. like dates in the order of 08, 11, 12, 24, 24, 27, 27, 31, etc "

OK, the order "08, 11, 12, 24, 24, 27, 27, 31, etc." does not seem random, does it? It is pretty much the order you requested - ascending.
I'm guessing that all those dates are in may, so you really are getting what you requested for: records from Employees table with createDt greater or equal to 5th of may and sorted in ascending order.

But you are saying that the dates order seems weird to you, you were expecting 05, 06, ..., and you got 08, 11, 12, 24

Oh! What seems to be bothering you is the fact that you have some gaps between the dates and that the dates do not start with May 5th. Is that it? Well, then, simple answer is: those dates are simply not present in the Employees table.

You ask elsewhere ".. how do I limit that to send only 10 records?"
Ok, so let me guess what you would like to get.

You would like to see 10 consecutive dates starting with may 5th and the records which were created for each date.

In that case you have to "generate" those dates and then join them with your Employees table taking into account that for some of the dates you will have no row - hence LEFT JOIN.

```
with dates as
 (select date '2021-05-05' + (level - 1) d from dual connect by level <= 10)
select e.* 
  from dates d 
  left join employees e 
    on e.createDt = d.d
order by d.d
```

or, if the createDt contains time component

```
with dates as
 (select date '2021-05-05' + (level - 1) d from dual connect by level <= 10)
select e.* 
  from dates d 
  left join employees e 
    on e.createDt >= d.d and e.createDt < d.d + 1
order by d.d, e.createDt
```

I'm not sure if this is it, though

Also: you may use the literal '05-MAY-21' but only if you are absolutely sure that your session uses this exact date format. It's safer to use the [datetime literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) or to_date function ( to_date('05-MAY-21', 'DD-MON-YY') )